# How can i render data using axios.get

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

i'm working on a small project using **PHP** and **Axios**, i'm trying to render data in a html table using **v-for** but it doesn't work since i get the server feedback, i mean i get the **json** response correctly by 
when i do `<td>{{user.id}}</td>` i get a black td 
This is my code,
the function in question is **loadUsers** :

```
export default{
  data(){
     return {
        users : {}
     }
  },
  methods:{
     addCustomer(){
        //var form = document.querySelector('#add-customer');
        var formData = $('#add-customer').serialize();
        axios.post('/Thirdparty', formData).then(function(response){
           helper.validation(response.data);
           //alert(response.data.error);
        });
     },
     loadUsers(){
        axios.get('/Thirdparty/loadUsers').then((data) => {
           this.users = data.data;
        });
     }
  },
  created(){
     let self = this;
     self.loadUsers(); 
  }
}
```

My PHP Code :

```
public function loadUsers(){
    echo $this->data['users'] = json_encode(array('id' => 1));
}
```

My Html Code :

```
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Result in the console is correct but i see the json response correctly but VueJs won't render data in `td` tag i get a blank `td`

Comment: Any help please ?

Comment: I'm not a huge expert in Vue but it seems like you're not updating the state correctly so the component doesn't re-render when the data comes in. It could have something to do with array change detection https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be doing this...

```
loadUsers(){
    axios.get('/Thirdparty/loadUsers').then((res) => {
       this.users = res.data.users;
    });
 }
```

You also don't need to define a self var you can use this..

```
 created(){
  this.loadUsers(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with computed property , something like this :

```
computed: {
   loadUsers(){
    axios.get('/Thirdparty/loadUsers').then((res) => {
       this.users = res.data.users;
    });
 }
}
```

Or if you want to get data , on component rendering maybe mounted is another option

And in ES6 you can use straight this .... maybe using inside the varibale self , it can occurs problem with the scope ?

```
created(){
     this.loadUsers(); 
  }
```